# Waiting for the element. Different effects depending on whether or not to appear. Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a question because I have an element on the page that appears randomly. If it appears, I want to wait until it hides. If it does not appear, I want to go to the next test step (the next line of code, next function). How I can do this?

My code:

```
def elementwait(self):
    WebDriverWait(self.driver, 15).until(
        expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable(myPathtoElement)
    )
    loader = self.driver.find_element(*myPathtoElement)
    WebDriverWait(self.driver, 15).until(
        expected_conditions.invisibility_of_element_located(myPathtoElement)
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Try like that.

```
def elementwait(self):
 if len(WebDriverWait(self.driver, 15).until(expected_conditions.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,"myPathtoElement"))))>0 :
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("myPathtoElement").click()

 else:
    loader = self.driver.find_element(*myPathtoElement)
    WebDriverWait(self.driver, 15).until(
        expected_conditions.invisibility_of_element_located(myPathtoElement)
    )
```

Comment: Ok will give you other solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to wait until the element appears and then, if successful, wait until it disappears. If not successful, you will need to catch the timeout exception and then continue. To do this, you will want to wrap the waits in a `try-catch` so that if the element never appears, the timeout exception is captured and execution can continue.

```
def element_wait(self):
    try:
        wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 15)
        wait.until(expected_conditions.visibility_of_element_located(myPathtoElement))
        wait.until(expected_conditions.invisibility_of_element_located(myPathtoElement))
    except TimeoutException:
        // nothing to do here since the element did not appear
    // continue execution here
```

A few notes:

1. I changed the name of the method to `element_wait()` since that's more python-y. You probably want a more descriptive method name but I can't think of one that isn't really long... `wait_for_element_to_appear_and_disappear()` or maybe something more specific like `handle_loader()`, etc. See [python naming conventions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions) for more info. You probably want to change your variable names to be more python-y also, e.g. `myPathtoElement`.
2. I stored the wait in a variable since you ended up using it twice.
3. I changed the first wait from wait for clickable to wait for visible since you weren't actually clicking the element.
4. You never used `loader` so I'm not sure if it was intended to be there in the first place so I removed it.

Comment: Have I can create a continue ? Because I have a problem with this. Maybe In continue I can write that go to next step if element isnt on the site ? Can you help me ?

Comment: Given the code you posted in your question, I wasn't sure where the script would go from there. If you wanted more code in the `element_wait()` method, you would add it in the `//continue execution here` area. It's possible that this method would just end and the execution would continue in the main script or at least another location.